# Контекстное меню проводника

Tags: windows, winapi

Я хотел бы сделать подобие стандартного проводника виндоуз, просто удобное, с нужными мне фишками. Не могу найти информацию, можно ли вызвать стандартное контекстное меню проводника (попап по клику правой кнопкой мыши)?

Answer (score 3):

```
procedure TForm1.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
var 
ContextMenu : IContextMenu; 
menu : HMENU;
begin 
FIShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf(Handle, 1, ShellItem(ListView.Selected.Index). ID, 
IID_IContextMenu, nil, ContextMenu); //FIShellFolder-переменная, которую нужно инициализировать "выше"
menu := CreatePopupMenu(); 
ContextMenu.QueryContextMenu(menu, 0, 1, $7FFF, CMF_EXPLORE); 
TrackPopupMenu(menu, 
TPM_LEFTALIGN or TPM_LEFTBUTTON or TPM_RIGHTBUTTON or TPM_RETURNCMD, 
Mouse.CursorPos.x, Mouse.CursorPos.y, 0, Handle, nil); 
DestroyMenu(menu); 
end;
```

Я думаю пример на Дельфях поможет..

Comment: Попробовал ваш пример, но мне пишет ошибку:
[Pascal Error] Sdup.pas(65): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IContextMenu'
[Pascal Error] Sdup.pas(68): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'FIShellFolder'
[Pascal Error] Sdup.pas(68): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ShellItem'
А рефакторинг почему-то не смог найти мне подходящий для них юнит.

Comment: ActiveX, ComObj, ShlObj

Comment: //FIShellFolder-переменная, которую нужно инициализировать "выше"
Глаза чем то обшиты?!!!!

Comment: Спасибо! Нашел пример http://www.delphisources.ru/files/sources/system/2006_year/virtual_listview.zip
Для этого примера ваше дополнение подходит без вопросов, там все на Shell построено. Т.е. меню-то теперь вызывается, но оно бездейственно. Как его заставить обрабатывать выбор пункта из списка(открыть, копировать.., свойства)?

Answer (score 0):

Контекстное меню проводника - это COM объект, реализующий интерфейсы IContextMenu и IShellExtInt. Возможно и есть какой-то способ, который позволит переиспользовать этот COM в своем приложении. Начать поиск подходящего API, наверное, можно отсюда: [Creating Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067(v=VS.85).aspx).